# Обратиться к классу при помощи переменной до php 5.3

Tags: php

Есть код который при загрузке на хостинг не работает из за более старой версии PHP. Причина в ошибке `syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`.

А именно: **Начиная с версии PHP 5.3.0, стало возможным обратиться к классу с помощью переменной.**

Пример:

```
static function template_module_call($param) {
    $className=mb_strtolower($param[1]);
    if (General::check_module($className, 0)) {
        $call='Cli_'.$className;
        return $call::templater_call($param);
    } else return ' ';
}
```

Каким образом можно поправить такие места?

Comment: Может проще хостинг сменить?

Comment: Хостинг который не предоставляет версию php 5.3 и выше - это ужасный хостинг. Тем более что версии ниже 5.6 уже не поддерживаются. Или вы просто не знаете где сменить версию?

Comment: Это не особо трудно, если иметь весь код перед глазами. Но вы устанете адаптировать ваш код с Namespace модели на примитив. Проще хостинг сменить, как писали выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php)

```
call_user_func(array($call, 'templater_call'), $param);
```

См. также:

1. [Функции обратного вызова](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php) (callback-функции). Смотрите Пример #1 -> Type 2
2. [Описание call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php)

PS. Естественно самый правильный путь - использовать более новую версию PHP, как посоветовали в комментариях